# Como criar um ArrayList de Objeto e iterar sobre o mesmo?

Tags: java

Preciso criar um `ArrayList` deste objeto, porém dentro do seu próprio método, e ter um método para devolver o array com o `Iterator`.

Estou tentando fazer deste modo, porém não acontece nada.

**MAIN.JAVA**

```
package banco;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
        int choose = 0, contador = 0;

        while(contador != -1) {
            System.out.println("(1) - CRIE UMA CONTA \n"
                     + "(2) - VISUALIZAR SALDO DA CONTA CORRENTE \n"
                     + "(3) - VISUALIZAR SALDO DA POUPANCA \n"
                     + "(4) - RETIRAR DINHEIRO DA CONTA CORRENTE \n"
                     + "(5) - RETIRAR DINHEIRO DA CONTA POUPANCA \n"
                     + "(6) - APLICAR DINHEIRO NA CONTA CORRENTE \n"
                     + "(7) - APLICAR DINHEIRO NA CONTA POUPANCA \n");
            choose = entrada.nextInt();

            switch(choose) {
            case 1:
                System.out.println("OPÇÃO ESCOLHIDA (1)");
                Banco nomeBanco = new Banco("UVA", "1234");
                nomeBanco.criarBanco();


            case 2:
            case 3:
            case 4:
            case 5:
            case 6:
            case 7:
            default:
                System.out.println("NÃO EXISTE ESTA OPÇÃO, TENTE NOVAMENTE...");
            }

        }

    }
}
```

**BANCO.JAVA**

```
/**
 * 
 */
package banco;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;

/**
 * @author saadt
 *
 */

public class Banco {
    private String nome;
    private String code;
    private ArrayList<Banco> bancos;
    Conta conta;

    public Banco(String nome, String code) {
        this.nome = nome;
        this.code = code;
        this.bancos = new ArrayList<Banco>();
    }

    public void criarBanco(){
        ArrayList<Banco> arrBancos = new ArrayList<Banco>();
        Banco novoBanco = new Banco("UVA", "1234");
        arrBancos.add(novoBanco);

        System.out.println(arrBancos);
    }




}
```

Comment: Por que um banco teria como propriedade de instância uma lista de bancos? E qual a intenção do método `criarBanco` dentro de `Banco` que cria um `Banco` e o insere em uma variável de método `ArrayList<Banco>` que logo é descartada? Não consegui fazer sentido do seu código, principalmente da classe `Banco`

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado, desculpa eu sou novato em Java. Eu só queria encapsular esses métodos para deixa-los seguros, sem o risco de serem alterados. Mas o que realmente eu quero fazer é o seguinte: "Eu poderei ter vários bancos, e nesses bancos poderão ter várias contas, contas poupança ou corrente em cada um deles". Como eu faço isto utilizando o ArrayList e utilizando todas as boas práticas?

Comment: Crie um método que devolva um item através de sua posição e itere sobre ele no main. Crie outro que devolva o tamanho da lista tambem para conseguir iterar corretamente. Fazer isso na classe especifica, ao meu ver, é violacao do principio de responsabilidade unica.

Comment: @Articuno, acabei de responder acima, poderia me ajudar em relação ao código sobre o que eu falei?

Comment: Apenas uma pequena curiosidade, porque motivo tem todos os textos do seu programa em CAPS ? É um programa para pessoas com deficiências visuais ?

Comment: A minha dica continua a mesma, para todos os casos citados(listar bancos e listar contas). Mas algo que eu náo faria é por a lista dentro das classes especificas, porque uma classe Banco deve representar apenas um banco e nao uma lista, o mesmo para a classe Conta. O main ou outra classe principal é quem deveria cuidar disso.

Comment: @Articuno, entendi! Só que é o seguinte, se eu colocar o new ArrayList no main beleza, eu sei fazer. Porém eu queria deixar tudo mais seguro e em boas práticas. Eu gostaria de utilizar o ArrayList criando métodos, como por exemplo: Inserir no determinado ArrayList por metódo, pegar no determinado arrayList por método. E isto eu não sei, esta é a minha dúvida. Poderia me ajudar?

Comment: Defina "boas praticas". Porque pra mim não faz muito sentido isso.

Comment: @ThiagoSaad O próprio ArrayList apresenta os métodos que você procura. O que você precisaria fazer é criar os mesmos métodos na classe que você quer, e chamar o método do ArrayList nesse novo método. Por exemplo um `private void addBanco(Banco banco)` vai executar `bancos.add(banco)` dentro de seu corpo. É isso do que você precisa?

Answer (score -1):

Vou responder a ti por etapas:

1. Tire o seu menu principal de dentro do `while`, pois ele repetirá a todo momento dentro do seu código. Isso polui a interface com o usuário.
2. No seu menu não está mencionado que `-1` é a saída do seu programa.
3. Para iterar o conteúdo do seu `ArrayList`, pode utilizar o conceito do lambda (Java 8 - exemplos nesse link: https://www.mkyong.com/java8/java-8-foreach-examples/). 
   Um exemplo:

   ```
   arrBancos.forEach(ab-> System.out.println(ab.code + " - " + ab.nome));
   ```
4. Não precisa declarar dois `ArraysList` na sua classe Banco. Você pode declará-lo juntamente com os outros atributos, sendo que no método você pode receber os atributos das contas como parâmetros e inseri-los dentro do `ArrayList`. 
   No seu código `main` permita a opção de inserir os valores do nome e
   conta para que possa passar para o seu método e adicionar a sua
   lista.

Após adicionado, você pode iterar usando o lambda, como descrevi no **item 3**.
Espero ter ajudado, se precisar pode postar sua dúvida.

Comment: Seria interessante você editar a resposta apresentando o código com as alterações sugeridas